# Virtuemart duplicate URL for products assigned to 1+ categories

Tags: virtuemart

I've this travel site in joomla+virtuemart http://couponviaggio.it/, and we're having some SEO problems caused by duplicate products URLs that stay in 1+ categories.
For example:
`couponviaggio.it/regioni-italiane/regione-abruzzo/hotel_city_montesilvano-detail.html`
`couponviaggio.it/mare/vacanze-mare-abruzzo/hotel_city_montesilvano-detail.html`

This is the same product, and it's accessible by 2 different URLs, because it stays in 2 different categories. 
I want to make something like:
`couponviaggio.it/hotel_city_montesilvano-detail.html`
for every product.

How can I do this?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot adjust Virtuemart's SEF URLs too much on it's own. VM have only few options in VM | Configuration | Configuration | SEO Settings tab.

For more SEF configuration options you need to use some dedicated SEF Extension, and I personally prefer [sh404SEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/sef/sh404sef) since the dawn of Joomla.

In sh404SEF Configuration, besides numerous general options, there is a tab for configuring URLs for most popular extensions, among which is also Virtuemart.

[image: sh404SEF VM Config]

From the screenshot above you can see that sh404SEF allows you to configure product URLs to your liking, either by using one or more categories, or not using them at all, which is your requirement.

Only drawback here is that sh404SEF is a commercial extension, but I am not aware of any other free solution.

UPDATE 2016-03-27:
My opinion about "Possible Duplicate VM URLs Issue" you can find on next OP's post:
[Strange Redirects from google after sh404sef plugin + virtuemart](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15682/strange-redirects-from-google-after-sh404sef-plugin-virtuemart).

Comment: You are sure that this can be possible at 101% with this plugin?