# Strange Redirects from google after sh404sef plugin + virtuemart

Tags: virtuemart, redirect, sh404sef

This site [couponviaggio.it](http://couponviaggio.it) it's a travel company e-commerce site, configured with Virtuemart.
As i think you know, Virtuemart has huge problems of duplicate contents (product that stay in 1+ categories), so i've installed sh404sef to remove categories from URLs like:
site.it/product

After this, now the problem is:

- I take this offer:
  [couponviaggio.it/village-il-girasole-corigliano-calabro-detail.html](http://couponviaggio.it/village-il-girasole-corigliano-calabro-detail.html)
- I search it in google, by the title for example: "Offerta Coupon
  vacanza mare Il Girasole Village,Corigliano Calabro sullo Jonio" The 
  first link is correct, when i open this, it goes to another page:
  [couponviaggio.it/hotel-mistral-oristano-detail.html][3]...It do a
  redirect to an insensate page!

But, if i copy the link in the url bar, it goes to the correct page..strange..
This thing happens for several offers, it's for 4 week that the problem persist, and i'm going crazy.
Can you help me? :)
Thank you guys,
regards from italy

Answer (score 1):

When I answered you previous Q '[Virtuemart duplicate URL for products assigned to 1+ categories](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/virtuemart-duplicate-url-for-products-assigned-to-1-categories/15457#15457)'
I didn't realize that your main concern and the reason for asking how could you eliminate any category from product URL, was "Duplicate VM Content issue" from the SEO point of view.

I think that is NOT AN ISSUE AT ALL!

Even Google in it's official documentation [Duplicate Content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) at the very begining clearly says:

> Examples of **non-malicious duplicate content** could include:
>
> - Discussion forums that can generate both regular and stripped-down
>     pages targeted at mobile devices
> - **Store items shown or linked via multiple distinct URLs**
> - Printer-only versions of web pages

Even on VM Forum there are topics regarding that 'issue', like [Duplicate content because of Virtuemart Product Category SEF alias?](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=123646.0) and others.

Clearly, having product in multiple categories and hence reachable by multiple URLs **would not constitute malicious duplicate content** as Google defines it in aforementioned article.

Otherwise, milions of web stores would never have multiple categorizations, which they regularly use every day.